# How to install only single dokku plugin?

Tags: dokku

I am trying to add a dokku plugin, but when I run plugins-install it tries to somehow re-install ngingx plugin which fails and it doesn't seem like I can install a single plugin.

I've read about pluginhook, but I don't seem to be able to find a way to run it to install just one plugin.

Can I just remove the plugins that has issues (move it out of the folder) and run the command and put it back or something?

Do I have to keep re-installing plugins each time I want to install a new one?

I am new to dokku, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All resolved itself as I updated dokku and then plugins-install worked without any issues.